# How to retrieve exceptions of recurring event (custom and deleted occurrences)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, recurrence, microsoft-graph-calendar

If I use the [List event instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call like this ({{ccc}} are Postman variables):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{RecurrEventID}}/instances?startDateTime={{start_datetime}} &endDateTime={{end_datetime}}
```

... I get *all* occurrences in the date range.

1. Is there a way to retrieve only the custom occurrences and deleted occurrences?
   They are not in the output of the [Get event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call either.
2. If not, how do I distinguish custom and deleted occurrence from the regular ones in the output of the [List event instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call? Especially for deleted occurrences, it would be far too much work to try and calculate them from the output.